# Visualizing decision tree : IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, decision-tree

Below decision tree :

[image]

Is generated using code :

```
dt = DecisionTreeClassifier()
dt = clf.fit([[1],[2],[3]], [[3],[2],[3]])

dot_data = export_graphviz(dt, out_file=None, 
                         feature_names=['1' , '2' , '3'],  
                         class_names=['true' , 'false'],  
                         filled=True, rounded=True,  
                         special_characters=True)  
graph = graphviz.Source(dot_data)  
graph
```

If I use instead :

```
dt = DecisionTreeClassifier()
dt = clf.fit([[1],[2],[3]], [[2],[3],[4]])

dot_data = export_graphviz(dt, out_file=None, 
                         feature_names=['1' , '2', '3'],  
                         class_names=['true' , 'false'],  
                         filled=True, rounded=True,  
                         special_characters=True)  
graph = graphviz.Source(dot_data)  
graph
```

error is returned :

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/sklearn/tree/export.py in node_to_str(tree, node_id, criterion)
    284                 node_string += 'class = '
    285             if class_names is not True:
--> 286                 class_name = class_names[np.argmax(value)]
    287             else:
    288                 class_name = "y%s%s%s" % (characters[1],

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Is this a quirk of the visualization as the classifier trains correctly ?

Comment: I haven't run the code yet, so perhaps this doesn't work, but you changed your features to include '4' in the second block. Did you try adding that to the list of `feature_names`? i.e. try `feature_names=['1' , '2', '3', '4']`

Comment: @Paul thanks, yes, tried 'feature_names=['1' , '2', '3', '4']' but same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there is one typo in your code. You are using `clf.fit` whereas it should be `dt.fit`.

Secondly, in the second instance you are specifying three labels, namely `['2','3','4']` whereas you are specifying the class labels as only `true` and `false` which is wrong, since you are clearly using more than 2 labels and it can't map an array of size 2 (class names) to an array of size 3(your actual labels). So basically you need to add another label besides `true` and `false` and it should work correctly.

```
dt = DecisionTreeClassifier()
dt = dt.fit([[1],[2],[3]], [[2],[3],[4]])   #It should be dt.fit not clf.fit

dot_data = export_graphviz(dt, out_file=None, 
                     feature_names=['1' , '2', '3','4'],  
                     class_names=['true' , 'false','something_else'],  
                     filled=True, rounded=True,  
                     special_characters=True)
```

Now it should work correctly. Feel free to name the third label as you like. The error basically occurred since you didn't specify anything for the third label, hence it could not map the actual labels (i.e. `2`,`3` and `4`) to the ones you specified in the class_names, i.e. `true` and `false`.